# Java While Loop creating random numbers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Was looking for an answer on here but couldnt really find what I was looking for.
So I'm new to learning Java and wanted to make a small lotto simulation where you have 6 random generated numbers from 1-99 and another 6 random generated numbers. I'm trying to create a while loop which prints all 12 numbers, compares them if they are equal or not and printing the amount of tries it took to get all numbers right. If they match up, the loop should end.
Now I am kinda stuck because the numbers are getting generated only once. So it generates 2x6 numbers and just keeps using those forever and I can't find a solution. Any ideas?

```
public class vorgegebeneZahlen {

public static int givenNumb1 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int givenNumb2 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int givenNumb3 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int givenNumb4 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int givenNumb5 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int givenNumb6 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);

public static int lottoNumb1 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int lottoNumb2 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int lottoNumb3 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int lottoNumb4 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int lottoNumb5 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
public static int lottoNumb6 = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);

public static void printNumber() {

    System.out.println("Your given numbers are:");
    System.out.println(givenNumb1 + " " + givenNumb2 + " " + givenNumb3 + " " + givenNumb4 + " " + givenNumb5 + " " + givenNumb6 + "\n");

    System.out.println("Your lotto numbers are:");
    System.out.println(lottoNumb1 + " " + lottoNumb2 + " " + lottoNumb3 + " " + lottoNumb4 + " " + lottoNumb5 + " " + lottoNumb6 + "\n");

}

public static int count = 0;

public static void play() {
    while (lottoNumb1 != givenNumb1 && lottoNumb2 != givenNumb2 && lottoNumb3 != givenNumb3 && lottoNumb4 != givenNumb4 && lottoNumb5 != givenNumb5 && lottoNumb6 != givenNumb6) {
        System.out.println( (count+1) + ". ");
        generateNumber();
        Vergleich.compare();
        count++;
    }
}
```

then I have a class for comparing

```
public class Vergleich {

public static void compare() {

    if (lottoNumb1 == givenNumb1 && lottoNumb2 == givenNumb2 && lottoNumb3 == givenNumb3 && lottoNumb4 == givenNumb4 && lottoNumb5 == givenNumb5 && lottoNumb6 == givenNumb6) {
        System.out.println("All numbers match, you won!" + "\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Numbers don't match, try again!" + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the code for `generateNumber()` do?

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that a match will be found in a finite amount of time.

Comment: It just prints the generated numbers. Should've called it "printNumbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your program by using arrays (instead of individual variables for each of given numbers and lotto numbers) and `Random` (instead of `Math.random`) e.g.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    static int n = 6;
    static int[] givenNumbers = new int[n];
    static int[] lottoNumbers = new int[n];
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static void generateNumbers() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            givenNumbers[i] = random.nextInt(100);
            lottoNumbers[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }
    }

    public static void printNumbers() {
        System.out.println("Your given numbers are:" + Arrays.toString(givenNumbers));
        System.out.println("Your lotto numbers are:" + Arrays.toString(lottoNumbers));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateNumbers();
        printNumbers();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Your given numbers are:[58, 9, 68, 33, 53, 6]
Your lotto numbers are:[24, 74, 74, 48, 51, 54]
```

Comment: Simplifies the code, but does not solve the problem.unless the loop is placed in the `generateNumber()` method.

Comment: Thank you! really helped me understand Arrays a lot more!

Comment: I just adjusted my code using your example but  It does not print the generated numbers. Just says "Your given numbers are:" and thats it. What could be the problem?

Comment: Thanks, but Im happy I solved it myself before your edit. Figured out you had to place the ToString into the print.

Comment: And this also solved my problem! It is now generating new numbers every run. Thanks a lot!